# Angular animation: can't find query

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

I'm learning Angular animations and i want to use stagger to fade in my list items one at a time when I click that *top 100 tag* and load the page. Unfortunately it says that it can't find the query I entered. Can someone see what I did wrong?

[image]

**I got the following animations code in my component:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-top100',
    templateUrl: './top100.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./top100.component.css'],
    animations: [
        trigger('topListAnimation', [
            transition(':enter', [
                query('.list-group-item', [
                    stagger(200, useAnimation(fadeInAnimation))
                ])
            ])
        ])
    ]
})
```

**template file**

```
<div @topListAnimation>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 listDiv">
        <div class="list-group">
            <a
                    [routerLink]="['/movies', movie?._id]"
                    href="#"
                    *ngFor="let movie of movies;
                let i = index"
                    [attr.data-index]="i"
                    class="list-group-item"
            >
                <h3>{{ i+ 1 }}</h3>
                <h3>{{movie?.title}}</h3>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                <span><h3>{{movie?.averageRating}}</h3></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template set the animation like so [@topListAnimation]

example animation of fade Out

```
export const FADE_OUT_TRANSITION = [
  trigger('fadeOut',  [
    transition(':leave', animate(700, keyframes([
      style({opacity: 1, offset: 0}),
      style({opacity: 0, offset: 1})
    ])))
  ])
];
```

and i import it in my controller like so

```
@Component({
  selector: 'lyx-ghost',
  template: '<div [@fadeOut]>Ghost Busters</div>',
  animations: [...FADE_OUT_TRANSITION]
})
export class GhostComponent {
}
```

for more cool effects check out animate.css